# Passing an array to class contructor as params list

Tags: php, class, object

I want to create a class object and pass its parameters as an array.

For example:

```
$array = array (
     'param1' => 123,
     'param1' => 456,
     'param2' => 789
);
```

that must be transformed into an array list of settings and passed to the constructor:

```
$a = new A();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the call_user_func_array http://php.net/call_user_func_array

```
<?php

      class A {

             public function __construct ( ) {
                    print_r ( func_get_args ( ) ) ;
             }

      }

      $A = new A();
      $params = array ( 'param' => 'value' , 'p1' => 'val' ) ;
      call_user_func_array ( array ( $A , '__construct' ) , $params ) ;
```

Comment: constructor is called twice, but I do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection

```
<?php
       class A {

              public function __construct ( ) {
                     print_r ( func_get_args ( ) ) ;
              }

       }

       $reflection = new ReflectionClass('A');
       $reflection->newInstanceArgs(array( 'a' , 'b' )) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class A
{
  public function __construct( $var=array() ) { print_r( $var ); }
}

$a=new A( array( 'foo','bar','baz' ) );
?>
```